# Branches not being ignored on CircleCi jobs

Tags: circleci

I am attempting to ignore ALL branches and only start the jobs on a tagged build if the tag contains the correct value.

I am using

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy_staging:
    jobs:
      - ios_deploy_staging:
        filters:
          tags:
            only: /^staging-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
          branches:
            ignore: /.*/
      - android_deploy_staging:
        filters:
          tags:
            only: /^staging-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
          branches:
            ignore: /.*/
      - ios_deploy_prod:
        filters:
          tags:
            only: /^prod-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
          branches:
            ignore: /.*/
      - android_deploy_prod:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^prod-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
```

Weirdly only the

> android_deploy_prod

is being ignored, all the remaining jobs run on all branches.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to formatting. It should have been:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy_staging:
    jobs:
      - ios_deploy_staging:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^staging-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
      - android_deploy_staging:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^staging-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
      - ios_deploy_prod:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^prod-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
      - android_deploy_prod:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^prod-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
```

Comment: To avoid having this issue , you have a circleci cli which can validate if your configuration is valid or not 

Command : 
circleci config validate .circleci/config.yml 

Output :
You are running 0.1.15195
A new release is available (0.1.16225)
You can update with `brew upgrade circleci`

Config file at .circleci/config.yml is valid.